# Traversing a tree using linked list structure

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a struct node which contains a next and a child.

```
struct Node{
Node *parent;
Node *next;
Node *child;
}
```

The following picture shows the structure of the tree.

How would I write a function that traverse that tree? without recursion ?
[image]

I have a pseudo code in my mind but not sure if its correct or no, because each node can have a child and I need to search using that child too

```
while ( root !=NULL)
{

root = root->next;
}
```

I would like to visit all the nodes.

Comment: Means you are asking without recursion as question  or you don't want to use recursion ?

Comment: I don't want to use recursion

Comment: What do you mean by "traverse"? Follow one path through the tree or visit all nodes?

Comment: @MOehm visit all nodes

Comment: You need to have two pointers in struct to traverse left and right .

Comment: @ameyCU I have next and I have a child which goes to next child If it has one, and I have parent pointer

Comment: @andre What if it has two or more childs ? Then you will need to come back to parent  and then go the other way .

Comment: @ameyCU sorry I modified it, I have one parent pointer too

Comment: @ameyCU can you help please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90212/discussion-between-andre-and-ameycu).

Comment: This is just a binary tree. look for binary tree print or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you tree look like this:

```
-> grandma
    -> dad
        -> me
        -> sister
            -> niece
        -> brother
    -> uncle
        -> cousin
```

where indentation means a level of ancestry. The recursive function is simple:

```
void traverse_rec(const Node *node)
{
    if (node) {
        process(node);
        traverse_rec(node->child);
        traverse_rec(node->next);
    }
}
```

This can be rewritten as a loop. If the current node has a child, that's the next node to visit. Otherwise, you want to visit its sibling. But the node may not have actually a sibling. Because you have a link to the parent node (and the root node's parent should be ´NULL), you can backtrack up the tree until you find a sibling to follow or until the node is `NULL`.

```
void traverse2(const Node *node)
{
    while (node) {
        puts(node->name);

        if (node->child) {
            node = node->child;
        } else {
            while (node && node->next == NULL) {
                node = node->parent;
            }

            if (node) node = node->next;
        }
    }
}
```

This is more complicated than the recursive function, but it can be transformed to an iterator-like code, where you get the next node:

```
const Node *next(const Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;
    if (node->child) return node->child;

    while (node && node->next == NULL) {
        node = node->parent;
    }

    if (node) return node->next;
    return NULL;
}
```

With this "iterator", you can then write code like:

```
for (const Node *p = root; p; p = next(p)) {
    puts(p->name);
}
```

Comment: There is something I dont get here. When you go back to the parent, how will you then access another child than the same one, pointed-to by the child pointer?

Comment: That child would be `node->child->next` and it is visited after going back up and finding a node that has younger siblings to visit.

Comment: I see. But using a stack (as in my answer) does not need to have a pointer to parent, or to go back upfront. Am I right?

Comment: Your solution works even if the struct had only the "downward"  pointers `next` and `child`. You can convert a recursive solution to a stack/queue-based solution. In fact, recursion keeps the data you have in the stack in the program's call stack.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Notice BTW that the OP excluded a recursive solution  :).

Comment: I've included the recursive solution only for illustration; it is much cleaner, in my opinion. And when I tested my non-recursive code, I used it as reference.

Comment: @MOehm why parent should be null? Can you explain more the traverse2 function, I'm willing to learn.

Comment: Only grandma's parent should be null. The parents of all other nodes are not null. You can pick a node and walk through the algorithm with an example tree with paper and pencil.

Comment: while (node && node->next == NULL) {
                node = node->parent;
            }  this is I can't understand

Answer (score 1):

the tree convert to liner list by queue. and process  each node of liner list.

Pseudo code (not tested):

```
enqueue(q, root);//queue *q;
while(NULL!=(current_node = dequeue(q))){
    //do stuff current_node

    if(has_child(current_node)){//unnecessary, include for-loop
        for(node = current_node->child; node != NULL; node = node->next){
            enqueue(q, node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so its a level order traversal ?

Answer (score 1):

A Depth-First traversal can be done in the following way, without the need of the parent pointer:

```
  std::stack<Node*> Q; Q.push(root);
  while(!Q.empty())
  {  Node* node = Q.top(); Q.pop();
     // visit the node, do stuff
     if(node->next) Q.push(node->next);
     if(node->child) Q.push(node->child);
  }
```

Notice it is depth first because the child, if any, will be visited before the nodes at the same level, which are chained via the *next* pointer.